Pixel 4a not booting after flashing stock android
I have a Pixel 4a on hand, which had CalyxOs installed. I tried flashing stock android, and after running flash-all, I go the message log below, after which the device went off and did not boot up:
target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (8890 KB)...
OKAY [  0.359s]
writing 'bootloader'...
(bootloader) Flashing Pack version b5-0.3-6776359
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 0
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 1
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 2
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 4
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 5
(bootloader) Flashing partition xbl_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition xbl_config_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition aop_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition tz_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition hyp_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition abl_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition keymaster_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition devcfg_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition qupfw_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition uefisecapp_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition featenabler_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition logfs
OKAY [  0.313s]
finished. total time: 0.672s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.063s]
finished. total time: 0.063s
< waiting for device >

I tried to press power + volume down button but it just won't boot up. I tried with charger and without. Nothing.
What happened? What can I do to recover my device?

Sometimes it happens that the device is powered-on but the display is black - thus you think it is off. Try to force a reboot by pressing and holding power button for up to 60 seconds.

No amount of pressing seems to do anything here.
